# Converting AngularJS to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently converting an AngularJS HTML app to ASP.NET MVC and I have laid out pretty much everything and but when the page loads I see the controller(dashboard.js) but its not firing any function from the dashboard controller here is what I'm doing:

in my `_layout.cshtml` I have the following:

```
<html ng-app="app_angular" >
<head>
    <script src="~/script/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/script/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/script/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="~/script/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/script/angular/angular-cookies.js"></script>

    <script src="~/script/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/script/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script src="~/Scripts/myapp.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/controllers/dashboard.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/routes.js"></script>
</head>    
<body> 

<ng-view class="fx fx-slide page"></ng-view>

<div class="container">
    <h3 class="row title">
        <div class="col-xs-6">Dashboard</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right text-gray">{{ today | date:'MMMM d, y' }}</div>
    </h3>
</div>
<section ng-repeat="template in templates">
    <ng-include src="template"></ng-include>
</section>
<div class="container" ng-init="init()">

    <!-- Buttons --> 


</body>
</html>
```

`myapp.js`

```
var app_angular = angular.module('app_angular', ['ngCookies', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngAnimate']);
```

`dashboard.js`

```
'use strict';
app_angular
        .controller('dashboard', function ($rootScope, $scope) {
            debugger
            $scope.today = new Date();

         /* set template subviews */
        $scope.templates = {
            stream: "../../views/templates/firstqtr.html",
            modal: "../../views/templates/secondqtr.html",
            loan: "../../views/templates/thirdqtr.html"
        };

        });
```

`routes.js`(first approach: does not work)

```
app_angular
  .config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

      $routeProvider
        /* dashboard */
        .when('/', {
          controller: 'dashboard',
          templateUrl: '../../views/home/index'
        })
       .when('/home/about', {
          controller: 'dashboard',
          templateUrl: '../../views/home/about'
        })
       .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
  });
```

`routes.js`(second approach: does not work)

```
app_angular 
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) 
    {             
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', { templateUrl: '/home/index', controller: 'dashboard' })
            .when('/', { templateUrl: '/home/about', controller: 'dashboard' })

            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
    }])
```

What else I should be doing any help?

Comment: No console errors? Do you have an `ng-view` element?

Comment: no console errors, i have `ng-view/ng-include` element in the page, i have updated my question to reflect the changes

Comment: i'm thinking my routing is messed up?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that /home is the path of your MVC page

- you should change your angular routing to use path's that are
  relative to your page.
- add a view templates that are loaded into your
  page

the angular routing below would:

- load your mvc page /home/index and inject the template dashboard.html into ng-view element
  (MVC controller Home with Action Index is required)
- load your mvc page /home/index and inject the template about.html into ng-view element

Routes:

```
app_angular
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        /* dashboard */
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'dashboard',
            templateUrl: '../../views/templates/dashboard.html'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            controller: 'dashboard',
            templateUrl: '../../views/templates/about.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });
```

Remark:

You should rethink your approach of mixing MVC and anjularjs that not a good approach.
Try renaming your _layout.cshtml into index.html and start with a plain (ASP.NET MVC free) SPA.

Files:

- index.html
- views\dashboard.html
- views\about.html

Routes:

```
app_angular
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        /* dashboard */
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            controller: 'dashboard',
            templateUrl: '/views/about.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });
```